# Amazon IP no longer allowing MySQL connection (Error 104)

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am working on a group project that uses an Amazon EC2 server for hosting phpmyadmin. We have a PHP/MySQL website hosted on my school's server that makes database connections to amazon. Recently one of my group members created a script to populate our database with a bunch of entries and now when I go to our group's homepage there is a (104) error message and we can't connect to the database. I don't really understand the specifics of the problem because I didn't create the script but I was hoping for some advice as to what the issue is and how to fix it.

So far I have rebooted my amazon instance, restarted mysqld, and restarted my apache2 server.

Below is what I believe caused the error.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include "connection.php";

    /*
        EXTREMELY HARD CODED XD
    */

    function rand_date($min_date, $max_date) 
    {
        $min_epoch = strtotime($min_date);
        $max_epoch = strtotime($max_date);

        $rand_epoch = rand($min_epoch, $max_epoch);

        return date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $rand_epoch);
    }

    function generateRandomString($length = 4) 
    {
        //$characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $characters = '1234abcd';
        $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
        $randomString = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) 
        {
            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
        }
        return $randomString;
    }

    $numOfSales = 1;
    echo "creating " . $numOfSales . " sales!<br>"; 
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numOfSales; $i++)
    {
        //randomUserId
        $randomUserIdNumber = rand(200000000, 200000200);
        $userId = $randomUserIdNumber;
        //echo "userId: " . $userId . " - (200000000-200001000)<br>";

        //randomTableNum
        $randomTableNumNumber = rand(1, 99);
        $tableNum = $randomTableNumNumber;
        //echo "tableNum: " . $tableNum . " - (1-99)<br>";

        //Min and Max Date for Orders
        $min_date = "2012-01-01 12:00";
        $max_date = "2015-02-01 12:00";
        $saleDate = rand_date($min_date, $max_date);
        //echo "saleDate: " . $saleDate . "<br>";

        //serveTime
        $serveTime = NULL;
        //echo "serveTime: " . $serveTime . "<br>";

        //ifApp
        $ifApp = 0;
        //echo "ifApp: " . $ifApp . "<br>";

        //ifCarry
        $ifCarry = 0;
        //echo "ifCarry: " . $ifCarry . "<br>";

        $populateSales = "INSERT INTO SALE (USER_ID, TABLE_NUM, DATE, ARRIVE_TIME) VALUES ('$userId', '$tableNum', '$saleDate', '$saleDate')";

        $query = mysql_query($populateSales);
        if ($query === TRUE) 
        {
            $sale_id = mysql_insert_id();
            echo "sale_id: " . $sale_id;
            $populateSalesArchive = "INSERT INTO SALE_ARCHIVE (SALE_ID, USER_ID, TABLE_NUM, DATE, ARRIVE_TIME) VALUES ('$sale_id', '$userId', '$tableNum', '$saleDate', '$saleDate')";
            $query = mysql_query($populateSalesArchive);
            if ($query == TRUE)
            {
                $deleteSales = "DELETE FROM SALE WHERE SALE_ID = '$sale_id' LIMIT 1";
                $query = mysql_query($deleteSales);
                if ($query == TRUE)
                {
                    echo "<h3>successfully added one record to SALE_ARCHIVE OK :) </h3>";
                }
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "<h3>unsuccessfully added one record to SALE_ARCHIVE :(:(:( </h3>"; 
        }

        //people per sale?
        $peopleAmount = rand(1, 4);
        echo "peopleAmount: " . $peopleAmount . "<br>";

        $numOfOrders = 0;

        echo "-------------------------<br><br>";
        for ($i = 0; $i < $peopleAmount; $i++)
        {
            $item1 = -1;
            $item2 = -1;
            $item3 = -1;
            $item4 = -1;
            $item5 = -1;
            $item6 = -1;
            $item7 = -1;
            $item8 = -1;
            $item9 = -1;
            $item10 = -1;

            $numOfOrdersPerCustomer = 0;
            echo "<b>Customer " . $i . "</b><br>";
            //beverage or alcohol? 0 beverage, 1 alcohol
            $beverageAlcohol = rand(0, 1);
            //echo "appetizerAmount: " . $beverageAlcohol . "<br>";
            if ($beverageAlcohol == 1) 
            {
                //echo "got alcohol - ";
                //alcohol
                $alcoholItemArray = array(120, 121, 122, 123, 124);
                $sizeOfAlcoholItemArray = sizeof($alcoholItemArray);
                $randomAlcoholNumber = rand(0, $sizeOfAlcoholItemArray - 1);
                $alcoholId = $alcoholItemArray[$randomAlcoholNumber];
                //echo "alcoholId: " . $alcoholId . " - (120-124)<br>";
                $numOfOrdersPerCustomer++;
                $item1 = $alcoholId;
            }
            else 
            {
                //echo "got a beverage - ";
                //beverages
                $beverageItemArray = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11);
                $sizeOfBeverageItemArray = sizeof($beverageItemArray);
                $randomBeverageNumber = rand(0, $sizeOfBeverageItemArray - 1);
                $beverageId = $beverageItemArray[$randomBeverageNumber];
                //echo "beverageId: " . $beverageId . " - (0-11)<br>";
                $numOfOrdersPerCustomer++;
                $item1 = $beverageId;
            }
            //appetizer? 0 no, 1 yes
            $appetizerAmount = rand(0, 3);
            //echo "appetizerAmount: " . $appetizerAmount . "<br>";
            if ($appetizerAmount == 1) 
            {
                //echo "got an appetizer - ";
                //appetizers
                $appetizerItemArray = array(20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27);
                $sizeOfAppetizerItemArray = sizeof($appetizerItemArray);
                $randomAppetizerNumber = rand(0, $sizeOfAppetizerItemArray - 1);
                $appetizerId = $appetizerItemArray[$randomAppetizerNumber];
                //echo "appetizerId: " . $appetizerId . " - (20-27)<br>";
                $numOfOrdersPerCustomer++;
                $item2 = $appetizerId;
            }
            //else {echo "did not get an appetizer<br>";}

            //lunch or dinner? 0 lunch, 1 dinner
            $lunchOrDinner = rand(0, 1);
            //echo "lunchOrDinner: " . $lunchOrDinner . "<br>";
            if ($lunchOrDinner == 0) 
            {
                //echo "<b>got lunch</b><br>";
                //lunch: soupSalad? 0 soup, 1 salad
                $soupSalad = rand(0, 1);
                //echo "appetizerAmount: " . $appetizerAmount . "<br>";
                if ($soupSalad == 1) 
                {
                    //echo "got a salad - ";
                    //salads
                    $saladItemArray = array(30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37);
                    $sizeOfSaladItemArray = sizeof($saladItemArray);
                    $randomSaladNumber = rand(0, $sizeOfSaladItemArray - 1);
                    $saladId = $saladItemArray[$randomSaladNumber];
                    //echo "saladId: " . $saladId . " - (30-37)<br>";
                    $numOfOrdersPerCustomer++;
                    $item3 = $saladId;
                }
                else 
                {
                    //echo "got a soup - ";
                    //soups
                    $soupItemArray = array(40, 41, 42, 43, 44);
                    $sizeOfSoupItemArray = sizeof($soupItemArray);
                    $randomSoupNumber = rand(0, $sizeOfSoupItemArray - 1);
                    $soupId = $soupItemArray[$randomSoupNumber];
                    //echo "soupId: " . $soupId . " - (40-44)<br>";
                    $numOfOrdersPerCustomer++;
                    $item3 = $soupId;
                }

                //lunch: sandwhich or burger? 0 sandwhich, 1 burger
                $sandBurger == rand(0, 1);
                //echo "sandBurger: " . $sandBurger . "<br>";
                if ($sandBurger == 1) 
                {
                    //echo "got a burger - ";
                    //sandwiches, burgers
                    $sandwichItemArray = array(50, 51, 52, 60, 61);
                    $sizeOfSandwichItemArray = sizeof($sandwichItemArray);
                    $randomSandwichNumber = rand(0, $sizeOfSandwichItemArray - 1);
                    $sandwichId = $sandwichItemArray[$randomSandwichNumber];
                    //echo "burgerId: " . $sandwichId . " - (50-61)<br>";
                    $numOfOrdersPerCustomer++;
                    $item4 = $sandwichId;
                }
                else 
                {
                    //echo "got a sandwhich - ";
                    //sandwiches, burgers
                    $sandwichItemArray = array(50, 51, 52, 60, 61);
                    $sizeOfSandwichItemArray = sizeof($sandwichItemArray);
                    $randomSandwichNumber = rand(0, $sizeOfSandwichItemArray - 1);
                    $sandwichId = $sandwichItemArray[$randomSandwichNumber];
                    //echo "sandwichId: " . $sandwichId . " - (50-61)<br>";
                    $numOfOrdersPerCustomer++;
                    $item4 = $sandwichId;
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                //echo "<b>got dinner</b> - ";
                //entrees
                $entreeItemArray = array(70, 71, 72, 73, 80, 81, 90, 91, 100, 101);
                $sizeOfEntreeItemArray = sizeof($entreeItemArray);
                $randomEntreeNumber = rand(0, $sizeOfEntreeItemArray - 1);
                $entreeId = $entreeItemArray[$randomEntreeNumber];
                //echo "entreeId: " . $entreeId . " - (70-101)<br>";
                $numOfOrdersPerCustomer++;
                $item5 = $entreeId;

                //dinner: dessert? 0 no, 1 yes
                $dessertAmount = rand(0, 3);
                //echo "dessertAmount: " . $dessertAmount . "<br>";
                if ($dessertAmount == 1) 
                {
                    //echo "got dessert - ";
                    //desserts
                    $dessertItemArray = array(110);
                    $sizeOfDessertItemArray = sizeof($dessertItemArray);
                    $randomDessertNumber = rand(0, $sizeOfDessertItemArray - 1);
                    $dessertId = $dessertItemArray[$randomDessertNumber];
                    echo "dessertId: " . $dessertId . " - (110-110)<br>";
                    $numOfOrdersPerCustomer++;
                    $item6 = $dessertId;
                }
                //else {echo "did not get dessert<br>";}
            }
            //query for adding orders

            //beverage
            if ($item1 != -1)
            {
                echo "beverage: " . $item1 . "<br>";

                $populateOrders = "INSERT INTO ORDERS (SALE_ID, ITEM_ID) VALUES ('$sale_id', '$item1')";

                $query = mysql_query($populateOrders);
                if ($query === TRUE) 
                {
                    $order_id = mysql_insert_id();
                    echo "order_id: " . $order_id;
                    $populateOrdersArchive = "INSERT INTO ORDERS_ARCHIVE (ORDER_ID, SALE_ID, ITEM_ID) VALUES ('$order_id', '$sale_id', '$item1')";
                    $query = mysql_query($populateOrdersArchive);
                    if ($query == TRUE)
                    {
                        $deleteOrders = "DELETE FROM ORDERS WHERE ORDER_ID = '$order_id' LIMIT 1";
                        $query = mysql_query($deleteOrders);
                        if ($query == TRUE)
                        {
                            //echo "<h3>successfully added one record to ORDERS_ARCHIVE OK :) </h3>";
                        }
                    }
                } 
                else 
                {
                    echo "<h3>unsuccessfully added one record to ORDERS_ARCHIVE :(:(:( </h3>"; 
                }
            }
            //appetizer
            if ($item2 != -1)
            {
                echo "appetizer: " . $item2 . "<br>";

                $populateOrders = "INSERT INTO ORDERS (SALE_ID, ITEM_ID) VALUES ('$sale_id', '$item2')";

                $query = mysql_query($populateOrders);
                if ($query === TRUE) 
                {
                    $order_id = mysql_insert_id();
                    echo "order_id: " . $order_id;
                    $populateOrdersArchive = "INSERT INTO ORDERS_ARCHIVE (ORDER_ID, SALE_ID, ITEM_ID) VALUES ('$order_id', '$sale_id', '$item2')";
                    $query = mysql_query($populateOrdersArchive);
                    if ($query == TRUE)
                    {
                        $deleteOrders = "DELETE FROM ORDERS WHERE ORDER_ID = '$order_id' LIMIT 1";
                        $query = mysql_query($deleteOrders);
                        if ($query == TRUE)
                        {
                            //echo "<h3>successfully added one record to ORDERS_ARCHIVE OK :) </h3>";
                        }
                    }
                } 
                else 
                {
                    echo "<h3>unsuccessfully added one record to ORDERS_ARCHIVE :(:(:( </h3>"; 
                }
            }
            //soup & salad
            if ($item3 != -1)
            {
                echo "soup or salad: " . $item3 . "<br>";

                $populateOrders = "INSERT INTO ORDERS (SALE_ID, ITEM_ID) VALUES ('$sale_id', '$item3')";

                $query = mysql_query($populateOrders);
                if ($query === TRUE) 
                {
                    $order_id = mysql_insert_id();
                    echo "order_id: " . $order_id;
                    $populateOrdersArchive = "INSERT INTO ORDERS_ARCHIVE (ORDER_ID, SALE_ID, ITEM_ID) VALUES ('$order_id', '$sale_id', '$item3')";
                    $query = mysql_query($populateOrdersArchive);
                    if ($query == TRUE)
                    {
                        $deleteOrders = "DELETE FROM ORDERS WHERE ORDER_ID = '$order_id' LIMIT 1";
                        $query = mysql_query($deleteOrders);
                        if ($query == TRUE)
                        {
                            //echo "<h3>successfully added one record to ORDERS_ARCHIVE OK :) </h3>";
                        }
                    }
                } 
                else 
                {
                    echo "<h3>unsuccessfully added one record to ORDERS_ARCHIVE :(:(:( </h3>"; 
                }
            }
            if ($item4 != -1)
            {   
                echo "sandwhich or burger: " . $item4 . "<br>";

                $populateOrders = "INSERT INTO ORDERS (SALE_ID, ITEM_ID) VALUES ('$sale_id', '$item4')";

                $query = mysql_query($populateOrders);
                if ($query === TRUE) 
                {
                    $order_id = mysql_insert_id();
                    echo "order_id: " . $order_id;
                    $populateOrdersArchive = "INSERT INTO ORDERS_ARCHIVE (ORDER_ID, SALE_ID, ITEM_ID) VALUES ('$order_id', '$sale_id', '$item4')";
                    $query = mysql_query($populateOrdersArchive);
                    if ($query == TRUE)
                    {
                        $deleteOrders = "DELETE FROM ORDERS WHERE ORDER_ID = '$order_id' LIMIT 1";
                        $query = mysql_query($deleteOrders);
                        if ($query == TRUE)
                        {
                            //echo "<h3>successfully added one record to ORDERS_ARCHIVE OK :) </h3>";
                        }
                    }
                } 
                else 
                {
                    echo "<h3>unsuccessfully added one record to ORDERS_ARCHIVE :(:(:( </h3>"; 
                }
            }
            if ($item5 != -1)
            {
                echo "entree: " . $item5 . "<br>";

                $populateOrders = "INSERT INTO ORDERS (SALE_ID, ITEM_ID) VALUES ('$sale_id', '$item5')";

                $query = mysql_query($populateOrders);
                if ($query === TRUE) 
                {
                    $order_id = mysql_insert_id();
                    echo "order_id: " . $order_id;
                    $populateOrdersArchive = "INSERT INTO ORDERS_ARCHIVE (ORDER_ID, SALE_ID, ITEM_ID) VALUES ('$order_id', '$sale_id', '$item5')";
                    $query = mysql_query($populateOrdersArchive);
                    if ($query == TRUE)
                    {
                        $deleteOrders = "DELETE FROM ORDERS WHERE ORDER_ID = '$order_id' LIMIT 1";
                        $query = mysql_query($deleteOrders);
                        if ($query == TRUE)
                        {
                            //echo "<h3>successfully added one record to ORDERS_ARCHIVE OK :) </h3>";
                        }
                    }
                } 
                else 
                {
                    echo "<h3>unsuccessfully added one record to ORDERS_ARCHIVE :(:(:( </h3>"; 
                }
            }
            if ($item6 != -1)
            {
                echo "dessert: " . $item6 . "<br>";

                $populateOrders = "INSERT INTO ORDERS (SALE_ID, ITEM_ID) VALUES ('$sale_id', '$item6')";

                $query = mysql_query($populateOrders);
                if ($query === TRUE) 
                {
                    $order_id = mysql_insert_id();
                    echo "order_id: " . $order_id;
                    $populateOrdersArchive = "INSERT INTO ORDERS_ARCHIVE (ORDER_ID, SALE_ID, ITEM_ID) VALUES ('$order_id', '$sale_id', '$item6')";
                    $query = mysql_query($populateOrdersArchive);
                    if ($query == TRUE)
                    {
                        $deleteOrders = "DELETE FROM ORDERS WHERE ORDER_ID = '$order_id' LIMIT 1";
                        $query = mysql_query($deleteOrders);
                        if ($query == TRUE)
                        {
                            //echo "<h3>successfully added one record to ORDERS_ARCHIVE OK :) </h3>";
                        }
                    }
                } 
                else 
                {
                    echo "<h3>unsuccessfully added one record to ORDERS_ARCHIVE :(:(:( </h3>"; 
                }
            }

            echo "numOfOrdersPerCustomer: " . $numOfOrdersPerCustomer . "<br>";
            $numOfOrders = $numOfOrders + $numOfOrdersPerCustomer;
            echo "<br>";
        }
        echo "-------------------------<br>";
        echo "numOfOrders: " . $numOfOrders;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Have you tested with iptables / selinux disabled?

Comment: I have not. How do I do that and what will it acomplish?

Comment: have you tried initiating a manual connection to the Amazon mysql server from your school server? this would help pinpoint the cause of the issue. if you can't connect, it might be iptables (Linux firewall) blocking the connection.

Comment: I have connected to phpmyadmin and the direct IP connection fine. My issue occurs with the connection statement in my php code